# Wrap VariableSizedWrapGrid when another element obscures it partly

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have the following XAML code.

```
<RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="400" Height="400" Fill="Green"/>
        <Rectangle Width="400" Height="400" Fill="Blue"/>
    </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
    <Rectangle Width="600" MinWidth="600" Height="600" Fill="Pink" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>
</RelativePanel>
```

The code generates the following page.

[image]

When the app window's width is dimminished, the app window looks like this.

[image]

How do I make the blue square wrap (get below the green square) when the pink square obscures it partly?

The exact same thing happen when I use the community toolkit's WrapPanel instead of the VariableSizedWrapGrid. The code below shows how it looks then.

```
<RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Rectangle Width="600" MinWidth="600" Height="600" Fill="Pink" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>
    <wrapPanel:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Rectangle Width="400" Height="400" Fill="Green"/>
        <Rectangle Width="400" Height="400" Fill="Blue"/>
    </wrapPanel:WrapPanel>
</RelativePanel>
```

Comment: Are you saying when you use the `WrapPanel` and resize the app window, the controls inside don't reflow to the right position?

Comment: @JustinXL Exactly. I have added the code displaying how I used the WrapPanel. Note that I only exchanged VariableSizedWrapGrid for WrapPanel. No other changes were made. Would any other changes to the WrapPanel perhaps have an effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially when you start resizing the page, the `WrapPanel`'s width isn't changing at all and that's why you don't see the green rectangle to go to the second row.

The trick is to give the `WrapPanel` a *right margin* that equals to the width of the pink one.

```
<wrapPanel:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,600,0">
```